# Target Platform, All CPU or X86 difference

Tags: visual-studio

I am confused what setting of target platform should be chosen to enable my application to run on all computers, regardless of the processor type.  I tried All CPU but it did not work on a few computers.

Thanks

Comment: which type of computers you had tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `x86` works on 32bit OS as well on 64bit OS, the same for `AnyCPU`. So what is the difference?
The difference lays in the way the JIT compiler emits the code of your application on the target computer.

When you use `x86 platform` the code emitted by JIT is always a 32bit code, also on 64bit systems.
This could be a problem if you don't have installed the correct 32 drivers/dll needed by your applications (The `Microsoft.ACE.OleDB` is one of these problematic libraries).

Conversely, when you use the `AnyCPU platform` the JIT emits 32bit code on 32bit systems and 64bit code on 64bit systems. And this is more problematic than x86 because you need the correct drivers for both systems. So I suspect that the reason your app fails on some systems is due to the lack of the correct (for the system bitness) libraries used by your app.

In doubt I think is better to use x86 platform unless you have very specific requirements for 64bit systems.